# axxdsp.h in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++

I have a dll which builds properly in VS 2005 . The dll includes "afxdisp.h" header file which is present in the default location (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\atlmfc\include) .

// piece of code

## ifndef _AFX_NO_OLE_SUPPORT

#include "afxdisp.h"

## endif

// ends

The same dll is not building in Visual Studio 2008 . It gives a lot of compile-time errors  saying many variables are not defined .

Is there some other equivalent of afxdisp.h in Visual Studio 2008 .

PS : I make use of the class COleVariant which is defined in afxdisp.h ( VS 2005 ) .

Comment: I've such file in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include.

Comment: To have better responses you should include what error message you get when copiling.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would that one of your VS installations is using some version of the Windows Platform SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) which comes with its own version of ATL (ATL 7) and that your code either depends on that or depends on the older ATL 3.

Compare the standard include paths in the preferences of both VS installations (i.e. not the project-specific include paths).

Answer (score 0):

The file is still there in Visual Studio 2008. Check to make sure your include paths are correct. Make sure they are pointing to your Visual Studio 2008 directories. Perhaps if you include the first few errors/warnings in your project, I can help you further.